# Is there a way to create a LaTex half matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, xtable

I am trying to use the xtable package to create a print-quality half matrix in R.  I can create the full symetric matrix with no problem but when I extract only the lower triangle matrix, I get the error shown below.

```
library(Matrix)
datamat1<-tril(data1) #extract lower triangle
library(xtable)
options(xtable.floating = FALSE)
options(xtable.timestamp = "")
xtable(datamat1, digits = 3)
```

The error that I get is: "no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('dtrMatrix', 'ddenseMatrix', 'triangularMatrix', 'dMatrix', 'denseMatrix', 'Matrix', 'xMatrix', 'mMatrix', 'Mnumeric', 'replValueSp')"

I know that converting the matrix to a half matrix also converts its class to dtrMatrix but there must be some way to export a lower triangle matrix in a publishable quality form.  I have also tried using the 'zoo' package but without any luck. How can this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe keep the original matrix and just set the upper triangle to missing. Then you'll still have a regular `matrix` object that `xtable` can handle. The code below also shows a couple of other options besides `xtable` for printing. (If you need the `dtrMatrix` class object for further processing, you can of course just create that separately from the object created below for printing.)

````
---
title: "My Title"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(gt)
library(xtable)
options(xtable.floating = FALSE)
options(xtable.comment = FALSE)
options(knitr.kable.NA="")
```

## Using `xtable`

```{r,  results="asis"}
set.seed(3)
m = matrix(1:16 + rnorm(16), nrow=4)
m[upper.tri(m)] = NA_real_

xtable(m, digits=3)
```

## Using `knitr::kable`

```{r}
colnames(m) = 1:ncol(m)
rownames(m) = 1:nrow(m)

kable(m, row.names=TRUE, digits=3)
```

## Using the `gt` package

```{r}
gt(as_tibble(m),
   rownames_to_stub=TRUE,
   digits) %>% 
  fmt_missing(columns=everything(), 
              missing_text="") %>% 
  fmt_number(columns=everything(), 
             decimals=3)
```
````

[image]